# OpenShift - Git v2.5.0 not found - can't clone app git repo

Tags: ruby, git, openshift, windows-10, cloning

So, the first official version of Git (v2.5.0) came out, and as my first OpenShift project, where I followed the [official tutorial](https://developers.openshift.com/en/getting-started-windows.html), and used Ruby v2.1.6p336, I came across the problem of ruby phc not finding any Git installed to clone the app repo.

Here's the cmd log:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.10240]
(c) 2015 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Nauro>Ruby --version
ruby 2.1.6p336 (2015-04-13 revision 50298) [x64-mingw32]

C:\Users\Nauro>Git --version
git version 2.5.0.windows.1

C:\Users\Nauro>rhc --version
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
rhc 1.36.4


C:\Users\Nauro>rhc app create python-2.7 -a test
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
Application Options
-------------------
Domain:     lab001
Cartridges: python-2.7
Gear Size:  default
Scaling:    no

Creating application 'test' ... done


Waiting for your DNS name to be available ... done

You do not have git installed, so your application's git repo will not be cloned

Your application 'test' is now available.

  URL:        http://test-lab001.rhcloud.com/
  SSH to:     55d4d6952d5271bce7000051@test-lab001.rhcloud.com
  Git remote: ssh://55d4d6952d5271bce7000051@test-lab001.rhcloud.com/~/git/test.git/

Run 'rhc show-app test' for more details about your app.

C:\Users\Nauro>
```

I don't think I want to use the Pre-Releases and want to make it work with this new version (although, it might work), because Git doesn't give me to choose an older version anyway (unlike Ruby).

Also, I should mention that there are 2 extra steps in the official version of Git installation process, not mentioned in the tutorial, because the didn't exist in the Pre-Releases. One allows you to choose between "Using MinTTY" and "Use Windows' default console window" in which I tried both options, and the other is "Enable file system caching", which I never checked.

The setup:

- Windows 10.0.10240
- Ruby v2.1.6p336
- Git v2.5.0 (first official release)
- phc v1.36.4

P.S.: I just started learning Ruby, Git, and OpenShift hosting with a simple [Hello World tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kLxBsN1CeW8), and got stuck, so I know nothing much beyond that.

Answered:
By keeping the install path on default and choosing "Use Windows' default console window", the app repo automaticaly cloned successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rhc command looks for git to be installed in these locations (along with being in your path first)

```
if RHC::Helpers.windows?
          guessing_locations << 
            discover_windows_executables do |base|
              [ 
                "git.exe",
                "#{base}\\Git\\bin\\git.exe", 
                "#{base}\\git.exe", 
              ]
            end
        end
```

https://github.com/openshift/rhc/blob/master/lib/rhc/git_helpers.rb#L24-L33

You should check what directory & name your git is installed with (I see you used Git in your question...) And make sure that it is either on your path (maybe close & reopen your terminal window) or that it is in one of those standard locations in the code

Comment: I changed the directory of git install path from "C:\Program Files\Git" to "Z:\Nauro\Programs\Git". Does this make a difference? (Here's temp link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/kry25xqgi643m6h/Screenshot%202015-08-19%2010.36.13.png?dl=0)

Comment: Aha! Yes, keeping the default path lets phc to find git. It has been cloned automatically now. Thank You!